# Can an opt out field be added to uidatepicker

Tags: swift

Is there a way to integrate an option for no entry in an UIDatePicker?  I’m thinking for example XX-XX-XXXX.  The reason for asking is Apple require developers to provide users with a choice whether they provide information like a date of birth.

Answer (score 1):

`UIDatePicker` is pretty strict about what it displays. You can't tell it to show anything other than dates and/or times in a specific range. You might find that `UIPicker` is useful, although you'll need to provide each picker entry from your own code.

If the issue is that some people may not want to provide this information, it might be better to include a "cancel" button somewhere that lets people dismiss the picker without making a choice. Rather than choosing some "X"-formatted "no entry" option, let them avoid making a choice.